# how to pass block to RSpec "with" expectation

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails

Tet say I have class

```
Class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def set_publication
      Publication.new do |publication|
        publication.owner_type = 'Foo'
        publication.owner_id   =  123
      end
      return 'something else'
  end
end
```

**Question:** How can I test the block that Publication new instance will receive

```
describe Foo, 'set_publication' do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new }

  it do
    Publication.should_recive(:new).with( ??????? ).and_return( double(:something) )
    foo.set_publication
  end
end
```

of course this is just a example of much complicated functionality in which I cannot use hash arguments like  this

```
Class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def set_publication
     Publication.new owner_type: 'Foo', owner_id: 123         
     return 'something else'
  end
end
```

and test it like this

```
describe Foo, 'set_publication' do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new }

  it do
    Publication.should_recive(:new).with( owner_type: "Foo", owner_id: 123 ).and_return( double(:something) )
    foo.set_publication
  end
end
```

thank you

---

**UPDATE**:  It seems it's bit unclear what I'm asking here, so :

I'm looking for way to ensure that `Publication.new` was called explicitly with set of arguments, in this case a block

so I suppose something like this

```
Publication.should_receive(:new).with(&block) # example
```

where the block parameters owner_type == 'foo' and owner_id == 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and_yield to accomplish this.

```
class Foo
  def set_publication
    Publication.new do |publication|
      publication.owner_type = 'Foo'
      publication.owner_id   =  123
    end
    return 'something else'
  end
end

class Publication
  attr_accessor :owner_id, :owner_type

  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

and the spec

```
describe Foo do 
  let(:foo) { Foo.new }
  let!(:publication) { Publication.new }

  it do
    Publication.should_receive(:new).and_yield(publication)

    foo.set_publication

    publication.owner_type.should eq 'Foo'
    publication.owner_id.should eq 123
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My only possible (and working) solution sofar is:

```
Class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def set_publication
      Publication.new &publication_block_params(123)
      return 'something else'
  end

  def publication_block_params(some_id)
    Proc.new do |publication|
      publication.owner_type = 'Foo'
      publication.owner_id   =  some_id # could be self.id but let's keep it this way 
    end
  end

end
```

and spec

```
describe Foo, 'set_publication' do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new }
  let(:my_block){ Proc.new {} }

  it do
    foo.should_receive(:publication_block_params).with(123).and_return(my_block)
    Publication.should_receive(:new).with( &my_block ).and_return( double(:something) )

    foo.set_publication
  end
end
```

and than separately create a spec for publication block params

```
describe Foo, 'publication_block_params' do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new }

  it do      
    publication = Publication.new &foo.publication_block_params(123)
    publication.owner_id.should   be 123
    publication.owner_type.should be 'Foo'
  end
end
```